# Using pg_admin III and PostgreSQL 8.1 (both test and development)

Tags: postgresql

I want to backup Development and restore it in test and vice-versa.

So when I do a backup of the db (in PGAdmin III), it backs it up. But
when I restore it, all primary key information is gone and no data is
in the tables.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't checked the "Only schema" checkbox on the ["Backup" dialogue](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.10/backup.html) by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgAdmin uses the client programs [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/app-pgdump.html) for making backups and [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/app-pgrestore.html) for restoring (it's only a GUI). Try to dump and to restore with these programs directly and see if you get any errors or warnings.

Offtopic: Support for version 8.1 ends this year, you should upgrade to a newer version.